# Does the system of linear equation $A^TAz=A^Tb$ always have a solution? ( $A^T$ is transpose of the matrix $A$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A \in \Bbb M_{n \times n} (\Bbb R), b \in \Bbb R^n $. If $A^T$ represents the transpose of the matrix $A$, does the system of linear equation $A^TAz=A^Tb$ always have a solution?

**Attempt:** I worked out a few examples and I suspect the above statement is true. In order to prove this statement, we need to prove that $\operatorname{rank} (A^TA:A^Tb) =\operatorname{rank}(A^TA)$ where $(A^TA:A^Tb)$ is the augmented matrix.

Since, $\operatorname{rank}(A^TA)=\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A^T),$ it would suffice to prove that $\operatorname{rank} (A^TA:A^Tb) =\operatorname{rank}(A)$

Could someone please give me hints to move forward. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The statement is true. It suffices to note/show that the column space of $A^TA$ is a subspace of the column space of $A^T$ and that $\operatorname{rank}(A^TA) = \operatorname{rank}(A^T)$.

Regarding the second statement: since we know that $\operatorname{rank}(A^T) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$, the quickest approach is to show that $A^TAx = 0 \implies Ax = 0$.  From there, the rank-nullity theorem gives us the desired result.

Comment: $A^Tb$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A^T$.  Since, $\dim \operatorname{Im} A^TA = \dim \operatorname{Im} A^T$. Therefore,augmenting $A^Tb$ to $AA^T$ won't modify the rank of the matrix $AA^T$. Correct?

Comment: @M That's technically correct, but augmenting a matrix with a column is not a particularly intuitive operation. I'd rather say that since the image of $A^TA$ is a subspace of the image of $A^T$ is a subspace with the same dimension, the two images are the same.  So, since $A^Tb$ is an element of the image of $A^T$, it is also an element of the image of $A^TA$, which means that it must be of the form $A^TAz$ for some vector $z$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I was stuck in the augmented matrix thing